# moving string to last in list of strings

Tags: c#

I have a List that has some items like this:

```
{"Pre Mdd LH", "Post Mdd LH", "Pre Mdd LL", "Post Mdd LL"}
```

Now I want to perform a condition that checks if an item in the list contains a specific string.

For example, I want to check in one go if the list contains an item that has "Mdd LH" in it.

How do I move ("Mdd LH") to last of same list when present in that list.

Example output:

```
 {"Pre Mdd LL", "Post Mdd LL", "Pre Mdd LH", "Post Mdd LH"}
```

Comment: did you try writing anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When I start a problem like this, I like to break it down into smaller pieces. It often helps me to get a piece of paper and a pencil and write out the steps I need to take to solve the problem. For example, the first step can be "find one of the elements that need to be moved". This requires some kind of search. I suggest you look at the documentation for `List` and `String` to find any methods that might help with this.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
if(list.Remove("Mdd LH"))
   list.Add("Mdd LH");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>{ "Pre Mdd LH", "Post Mdd LH", "Pre Mdd LL", "Post Mdd LL" };

if(stringList != null && stringList.Count > 0)
{
     var mustContainString = "Mdd LH"; 
     var firstMatchingElement = stringList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(mustContainString));

     if(firstMatchingElement != null)
     {
         //remove from index it is currently at and insert at end of list
         stringList.Remove(firstMatchingElement);
         stringList.Add(firstMatchingElement);
     }
}
```

Comment: but where are we searching for Mdd LH?

Comment: @PrathapShetty updated my answer to show how this is possible

Comment: x => x.Contains can you please explain what this part. what is x here?

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly.

Comment: `x => x...` is known as a lambda expression and is an anonymous function used to create a delegate. there is a great deal of information available regarding this if you search for it. In the context of this answer, it may help to think of `x` as an individual item in the `List<string>`

Comment: Thank you GregH for being helpful!

Comment: @PrathapShetty No problem. If this answer solved your issue, please accept it. Otherwise, feel free to let me know what is not working for you and I'd be glad to help